# Function not passing to main

Tags: c, function

I don't get any errors but I do not get the correct value. It keeps on printing 0! It looks like it's not reading my function and I really don't know what it could be.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

int rec(int base, int ex,int ans);

int main()
{
int base;
int ex;
int ans;
for(ex=2;ex!=1;){
printf("Enter a base and an exponent\n");
scanf("%d %d",&base,&ex);


rec(base,ex,ans);

printf("%d raised to the %d is %d \n", base, ex, ans);
}
return 0;
}

int rec(int base, int ex,int ans)
{

ans=pow(base, ex);  

return ans;

}
```

Comment: I see one problem right away: someone stole your tab-key.

Comment: So many dupes. Read the beginner tutorial more carefully. C is a pass-by-value language.

Comment: People should start learning programming with python. First things first: without tabs it won't work.

Comment: @fvdalcin Comment of the day (week? month? year?)

Comment: @fvdalcin Better yet, start with [Whitespace](http://compsoc.dur.ac.uk/whitespace/)

Answer (score 1):

You have two different `ans` in your code and you are interpreting them incorrectly. Assign the return value of `rec` to `ans` and delete the one in `rec`, since it is pointless. Here we go:

```
int main() {
    int base;
    int ex;
    int ans;
    for(ex=2; ex!=1;) {
        printf("Enter a base and an exponent\n");
        scanf("%d %d",&base,&ex);

        ans = rec(base,ex);

        printf("%d raised to the %d is %d \n", base, ex, ans);
    }
    return 0;
}

int rec(int base, int ex) {
    return pow(base, ex);    
}
```

Comment: The real answer should be _"get a good C book and read it. C is very simple to learn, but you *have* to learn it. Don't do it the hard way!"_

Comment: Couldn't possibly agree more!